Diamond texture modeling
Been trying to figure out how this guy did it but need some help. I tried to roughly make the shape by trying to subdivide to add more points but it didn’t correct doing everything manually. I have the reel and photos from someone else on what kinda diamond effect I’m talking about. Any advice or help is appreciated.
https://www.instagram.com/reel/CyoF-lrRoYh/?igsh=MW11N2Q2MWd1aDBrcg==
https://imgur.com/a/07rXQDy

A path you can try:
Add an UV Sphere, go to edit mode, select all, Face Menu > Poke faces.

select one of the newly created vertices, Select Menu > Select Similar > Amount of connecting edges (Shift G).
Scale as desired.

Add a Simple deform Modifier (Twist 60 degrees on Z axis) and a Bevel Modifier.

